# Problem reprojecting layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Using QGIS I am having issues in uploading a WFS, representing a geological map of Italy: when I upload it, the CRS sets automatically to EPSG:4326, ending up next to the Arabic peninsula. I used reproject layer, setting it to my project's CRS, EPSG: 32632. However, the new layer ends up in the same (wrong) spot. I tried to export and save as, then reproject layer, but it still ends up in the wrong spot. Is there something I am missing? [image]

Comment: Which CRS should the data be in? Not "which CRS do you want it to be in".

Comment: It should be in EPSG: 32632.

Comment: And which CRS does it have according to the layer properties?

Comment: Before the reprojection:  EPSG:4326, after the reprojections: EPSG: 32632, but still in the same (wrong) position. Sorry if I was being unclear.

Comment: This looks like a lat/lon swap to me, maybe check the axis order?